# Gmail displaying informational card at bottom of emails based on website mentioned in email

Tags: gmail

Gmail detected the website URL asp.net in an email and displayed the informational card seen here.  Any ideas how to control this displaying or not displaying automatically?

[image]

Comment: How do you know that it's not part of the email message that you received?

Comment: Where does it appear in the context of the message? Gmail ads don't generally work like that. I'd suspect a rogue browser extension. Do you get the same thing with other browsers?

Comment: @AlE It appears at the end of the signature block inline.  Ruben is right, it actually is part of the message that was received - it becomes part of the message body on replies, so I'm thinking maybe like what you said, it's a browser extension, and in this case on the other party's end.

Answer (score 1):

It appears at the end of the signature block inline. @Ruben is right, it actually is part of the message that was received - it becomes part of the message body on replies, so I'm thinking maybe like what @AIE said, it's a browser extension, and in this case on the other party's end.

Comment: Not strictly on the other end. The extension could be modifying your message before you send it. The Avast extension will do that (if you don't turn it off).

Comment: @AlE. Good point - in our case in hindsight I think it only occurs with this one contact so I think it's on their end, but otherwise yeah.